# SimpleLucene Questions(still supported, advantage or memory stream, explain an example)

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am using [SimpleLucene v1.0](http://simplelucene.codeplex.com/)  and [Lucene.Net v2.9.2.2](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) .

I am currently going through the examples and had some problems.

The first problem was the nuget package for SimpleLucene is not working. When you try to use it with their examples it won't compile as it is looking for some other version. This lead me to have to get the source code and just extract the .dlls giving me the above versions.

I believe that  `Lucene.Net v2.9.2.2` is not the newest version. This and the fact they have not corrected the nuget issue has made me question if they still are activity developing it.

In their [first example](http://simplelucene.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20an%20index&referringTitle=Documentation)  they mention that you can use a MemoryIndexWriter.

> Create an IIndexWriter. For file system indexes you can use the
>   DirectoryIndexWriter. You must specify the index location. Note: A
>   MemoryIndexWriter can be found in the tests project (for writing to an
>   in-memory index)

I been looking at the test files but not sure how it works. I am wondering if someone can explain the advantage or using the MemoryIndexWriter vs just storing it and also provide a simple example on how to use it.

In  they have

```
 public ProductQuery WithKeywords(string keywords)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
            {
                string[] fields = { "name", "description" };
                var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29,
                    fields, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29));
                Query multiQuery = parser.Parse(keywords);

                this.AddQuery(multiQuery);
            }
            return this;
        }
```

can someone explain to me what the fields array is for. I don't get what it is being used for.

Also does this library save much time version just using Lucene. I am starting to look at it as well as I just sort of jumped into SimpleLucene when it said it wrapped Lucene code into simpler calls.

Answer (score 1):

A MemoryIndexWriter will keep the entire index in RAM.  So once your program quits, you lose your index.  I suppose an advantage would be indexing and searching speed gains.  The DirectoryIndexWriter saves the index to disk, so it will be slower but you have a permanent index.  As to which is better, it just depends on what your particular requirements might be.

The fields array is specifying which fields of your documents you will be searching.  Notice they are using a MultiFieldQueryParser.

I personally have never used SimpleLucene, so I don't have an opinion one way or another.  I do feel that the Lucene API is not the greatest, but if you directly use it you might learn the inner workings of Lucene a bit better than using a wrapper.

Comment: Ah must be another mistake then with the fields. Now it makes a bit more sense in their example they don't have "description" anymore just "name" so it really should just be "name" as "description" does not exist.

Comment: Looks like that is just a standalone example, not related to the other examples.

Comment: Maybe but on the first page of the documentation it states "These examples make use of the following Product entity and static repository:" which does not have description.